The program may not crash when the program derefrences a null pointer?
I used to believe that the program would crash at once when dereferencing a null pointer.
But the code snippet below works well. What a surprise!
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    void test()
    {
        std::cout << "This is displayed\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo *f = nullptr;
    f->test();
}


Undefined behaviour basically means "anything can happen". You cannot reason anymore from that point. The only way to know what really happens (i.e. what the compiler did) is to look at the generated assembly code.

Common misconception, but this would be a safety feature of the type C++ does not have by default.

In C++ code that compiles is not necessarily a correct program, nor is a program that seems to run (correctly). Dereferencing a nullptr is not allowed by C++ (C++ virtual machine) and the C++ can generate any code it wants. (problems usually really show up when you do an optimized build, though your example seems to be an exception to that too:  https://godbolt.org/z/ebPqbKere). What you can see is that the whole function call is optimized out since "this" is not needed

Watch this : CppCon 2017: John Regehr “Undefined Behavior in 2017 (part 1 of 2)”.

when you cross a red traffic light you are not immediatelty hit by a car. Same here

Kindly do proper research before asking any question as recommend by the downvote button on the post's question and other SO guidelines.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

I used to believe that the program would crash at once when dereferencing a null pointer.  That is not a guarantee by C++.  C++ does not define what happens when a null pointer is dereferenced.  Which is why dereferencing a null pointer is classic undefined behavior.  Crashing from that is something that happens because of your platform.  Not all platforms will crash because of that.  (Your code does crash on my machine.)

Your code does not actually look at the this pointer that is passed as a hidden first argument to the member function. Which is how it survived. If you add something that would make use of this, like making the function virtual, it will crash as you expected.
https://godbolt.org/z/YfxcdqdPj
Of course undefined behavior is undefined, the compiler is permitted to do absolutely anything in this case, so logical reasoning will only get you so far.
If you enable optimizations, the compiler can also just plonk a ud2 instruction in there (explicit crash).
https://godbolt.org/z/YWfMefYoG

In your first para " ....   it will crash as you expected." is incorrect.    A more accurate statement would be " ....   it may crash as you expected."    It is certainly possible, in practice, to find examples of code similar to what you describe that DO NOT crash with some or all of the compilers (or build options) you have used.

Dereferencing nullptr is undefined behaviour. Thus it can crash, or not. Compiler can just skip/optimize away the line with this operation, because it is guaranteed from the user side, that nullptr will never be dereferenced.

Why does the compiler choose to ignore the dereferencing proccess? Just because there is no member variables for the struct?

Trying to reason why a compiler does something when you have undefined behavior makes no sense.

@John All optimizations are based on some assumptions. For example, you need to assume that vector is sorted to do binary search. So let's get those assumptions somewhere. Let's agree that users will follow some rules and deduce assumptions from there. Let's agree that user will never dereference nullptr. Then if the entire space of possible paths the execution can go we can assume that the paths which lead to *nullptr are impossible (user guarantees it). So let's remove them from code. The absence of member variables has nothing to do with it. It's about how optimization works in general.

In other words the compiler assumes it knows what you are doing (to make its own life a lot more easy) ;)

Why does the compiler choose to ignore the dereferencing process? It doesn't.  It analyses code constructs (based on rules, assumptions, etc) and, if that analysis determines that some set of constructs (operations on particular variables, complicated expressions, [inlined] function calls, etc etc) have no visible impact on program output, it is free to omit them.  That is just as true for constructs with undefined behaviour as it is for any other constructs (the only difference is that, with undefined behaviour, different compilers may produce different observable outcomes).
